# WSO2is Error after change Keystore - System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION

Tags: docker, wso2, docker-swarm, wso2-identity-server

I am running the WSO2is version 5.8.0 in Docker-Swarm, i script a compose for this mapping the files:

deployment.toml, wsocarbon.jks and  directory in servers.

After change the keystore i receive the error on login admin:
System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION

removing the mapping, the SSL Cert is not valid, but i login.

PS: i use traefik to redirect to container.

The stack deploy file:

```
  #IS#
  is-hml:
    image: wso2/wso2is:5.8.0
    ports:
      - 4763:4763
      - 4443:9443
    volumes:
      #- /docker/release-hml/wso2/full-identity-server-volume:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.8.0
      - /docker/release-hml/wso2/identity-server:/home/wso2carbon/wso2-config-volume
    extra_hosts:
      - "wso2-hml.valecard.com.br:127.0.0.1"
    networks:
      traefik_traefik:
            aliases:
                - is-hml
    configs:
      #- source: deployment.toml
      #  target: /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.8.0/repository/conf/deployment.toml
#
      - source: wso2carbon.jks
        target: /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.8.0/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks

      #- source: catalina-server.xml
      #  target: /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.8.0/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml

      - source: carbon.xml
        target: /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.8.0/repository/conf/carbon.xml
    #environment:
    #      - "CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx2g -Xms2g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
    #      - "JVM_OPTS=-Xmx2g -Xms2g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
    #      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2g -Xms2g"

    deploy:
        #endpoint_mode: dnsrr
        resources:
            limits:
                cpus: '2'
                memory: '4096M'

        replicas: 1

        labels:
          - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_traefik"
          - "traefik.backend=is-hml"
          - "traefik.port=4443"
          - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:wso2-hml.valecard.com.br"

configs:
  deployment.toml:
        file: ./wso2-config/deployment.toml

  catalina-server.xml:
        file: ./wso2-config/catalina-server.xml

  wso2carbon.jks:
        file: ../../certs/wso2carbon-valecard.jks

  carbon.xml:
        file: ./wso2-config/carbon.xml

networks:
    traefik_traefik:
      external: true
```

The password is some from the deployment.toml

Thz.

Comment: Format the code. It is not performing syntax highlighting.

Comment: Also add what you are trying to achieve, in the beginning.

Comment: Format your text properly to have better readability. E.g. Put file names under backticks --> `deployment.toml`

Comment: My goal is to have a ssl page with a valid certificate generated by a certifier, and removing the signed signature.